# Changing behaviour of .NET 3.5 bootstrapper generated by WIX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3, bootstrapper

I've got following problem:
I have built an installer with WIX. This installer contains a bootstrapper for .NET framework 3.5. First time installing the bootstrapper works like a charm. .NET framework 3.5 is installed. But for example after uninstalling and reinstalling the bootstrapper doesn't recognize that .NET framework 3.5 is already installed.

I found out following reason:
According to the bootstrapper log it checks this registry value:

> Reading value 'Install' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET
>   Framework Setup\NDP \v3.5\1033' Unable to read registry value

It searches for a localized version of the .NET framework (1033=German)

In my case I only have the English version of the framework installed (1031=English)

So I've only got 1031 as a subkey.

So my question is if it is possible to change the check from

> 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\1033'
>   to
>   'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\'

There is also a value named 'installed' and for the bootstrapper it doesn't matter which language for the framework is installed.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How was the bootstrapper created?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using burn as a boot-strapper you should use the DetectCondition attribute on the [ExePackage](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_exepackage.htm) element which will not run the .net framework installer if it detects is already installed.